# How to set a column to the number of rows based on a condition in the same row?

Tags: r, data.table

Basically, I want to do this:

```
dt <- data.table(category=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"))
dt$count <- nrow(dt[dt$category == dt$category])
```

That is, add a column "count" to the datatable, and set it to 3 for all "A" rows, 2 for all "B" rows and 1 for the "C" row.

I see a problem that the same datatable is being both set and filtered on, but I tried the following and it didn't work either:

```
dt <- data.table(category=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"))
dt2 <- dt
dt$count <- nrow(dt2[dt2$category == dt$category])
```

In practice, I have a more complex conditional I need to do, but if I could just get this to work I could probably solve the more complex one by myself.

I'm probably pushing filtering too far, but would appreciate any alternative suggestions how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: `dt[,count := .N, category]` ?

Comment: `dt <- data.frame(category=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"))
dt$count <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
if (dt[i,1]=="A"){dt[i,2]=1}
else{
if(dt[i,1]=="B"){dt[i,2]=2}
else{
if(dt[i,1]=="C"){dt[i,2]=3}}}}`

does that fits?

Comment: @Lionir, no. That is a very manual and inefficient solution. What are you going to do for 50 groups? You might as well try solving this using a pen and a paper. See mtotos comment above- both simple and efficient.